# Unity camera moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to move my camera detached from player, but it should have the same speed as the player. If the player is not in the camera´s visible area, the player should die.

I´ve already done player death if it is not in camera area.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far. Also highlight exactly where you struggle.

Answer (score 0):

Vague question, with a vague answer:

Add a script like this on the camera object:

```cs
float speed = ??;
GameObject player;

void Update() {
    var step = speed * Time.deltaTime
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, step)
}
```

and of course, instantiate the player variable in the Start function :)